# ain How does a proxy know which IP to forward responses to?

Tags: networking, proxy

At a conceptual level, how do proxies keep track of where responses should go?

Please correct me where I misunderstand, but we can think of a packet as a letter in an envelope, with a return address (source IP) and a destination address (server IP).

Proxies "cross out" the return address and put their own IP as the return address. When they receive a response from the server, how do they know which response goes to which user, since the server never sees the user's IP (that's the whole point), and therefore the response can't contain that information.

Comment: first understand that there are many kinds of "proxies" and they function differantly. SOCKS proxies use Session Layer headers to specify information about the proxy connection, whereas HTTP proxy simply relies on remembering the TCP circuit information on both ends, and otherwise functions at the application layer in HTTP commands. Tunneling "proxies" encapsulate one packet inside another. What kind of proxy are you asking about?

Comment: All of the above? :)

I guess the situation I'm trying to understand is if two users of the same proxy simultaneously make a request to the same server, how does the proxy know which response goes to which user?

Ideally, I'd love to understand this at a conceptual level. If packets are envelopes, then what are Session Layer headers? What is TCP circuit information?

Comment: because each incoming and out going connection are TCP circuits, so as they are negotiated during the three-way handshake, the system records information about the connection. when it receives a packet on that connection the proxy has no difficulty telling which is which, and which connection inbound requested that circuit.  its essentially the same question as why you can open up two different websites in multiple tabs, with the same answer, but with the added complexity of noting which outgoing connection is associated with which incoming connection. .